# Objective-C regex replace hex bytes?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

I have a binary file that I would like to regex search/replace hex bytes within it. I know there are command line methods for achieving this with Perl, however, if there's a way to do this with Objective-C/Cocoa I haven't been able to find it. The Perl method from the command line in OSX which works fine, although I would like to incorporate such in a Cocoa application - thanks

Binary file: TEST

```
45 76 65 6E 20 69 66 20 79 6F 75 20 66 61 6C 6C 20 6F 6E 20 79 6F 75 72 20 66 61 63 65 2C 20 79 6F 75 27 72 65 20 73 74 69 6C 6C 20 6D 6F 76 69 6E 67 20 66 6F 72 77 61 72 64 2E 20
```

Bytes to replace: 66 61 63
Replace with: 61 72 73

Perl example:

```
# grep -Z -r -l face TEST | xargs -0 perl -pi -e "s/\x66\x61\x63/\x61\x72\x73/g"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
// Change TEST to the absolute path of the file to read the data from
NSString *fileName = @"TEST";
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
if (data == nil || [data length] == 0) {
    return;
}
```

Your original question:

```
char bytes[]     = {0x66, 0x61, 0x63};
char new_bytes[] = {0x61, 0x72, 0x73};

NSRange range = [data rangeOfData:[NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:3] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
    return;
}

[data replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:new_bytes];
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

Edited for wildcard (I just used -1 for the wildcard and it can be in any spot):

```
char bytes[]     = {0x66, -0x1, 0x63};
char new_bytes[] = {0x61, 0x72, 0x73};

NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
if (dataLength < 3) {
    return;
}

char *data_bytes = (char *)[data bytes];

int dataLengthMinus3 = dataLength - 3;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < dataLengthMinus3; i++) {
    if (bytes[0] == -0x1 || data_bytes[i] == bytes[0]) {
        if (bytes[1] == -0x1 || data_bytes[i+1] == bytes[1]) {
            if (bytes[2] == -0x1 || data_bytes[i+2] == bytes[2]) {
                for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
                    if (new_bytes[z] != -0x1){
                        [data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(i+z, 1) withBytes:new_bytes[z]];
                    }
                }
                i += 2;
                continue; // Make this break if you only want to replace the first occurrence.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Inafziger, thanks for the example. I compiled your code (no errors), run it (no errors), although the file remains unchanged. Everything seems like it should work, so I'm a little perplexed. If you have any thoughts let me know.

Comment: Did you step through it in the debugger to see if it returns early?

Comment: After running the debugger it appears it's looking for this: 

`bytes char [3] 
[0] char 'B'
[1] char '='
[2] char '?'` and newbytes is: `new_bytes char [3] 
[0] char '='
[1] char 'H'
[2] char 'I'` — so it looks like an encoding issue?

Comment: Okay, I know why.  NSData wants to see values in decimal so convert the bytes in the two status from hex to decimal.

Comment: With the change to decimal it works perfectly! I'm just curious, why it has to be converted to decimal? Regardless of the reason, thanks so much for taking the time to provide such an excellent example — I really appreciate it ;-)

Comment: Well, the short answer is that you don't.  Lol, I had this issue before and that's the solution that I came up with.  When I started to look into WHY, I realized that it's just because when you set it the compiler assumes that it is decimal **unless** you specify another format.  To get hex, just precede the number with 0x.  Code updated again!

Comment: If you found this useful, please up vote the answer as well as accepting it.  Thanks and I hope that you find Stack Overflow (SO) useful and are able to help some others too!

Comment: heh — once I have the clout to up-vote this I definitely will. You're a gentleman and a scholar, and once again truly appreciate you taking the time for this!

Comment: @Inafziger, I have one more related question to this, The question is how could I subsitute one of the bytes for a wildcard? `I can post another question (different than this one if you would like so you get the points), so just let me know` — thanks!

Comment: Well, this is a bit more involved and I don't have the time to do it right at the moment, so you would probably be best to post it as a different question.  (One question though, will the wildcard always be in the same spot?  If so, that simplifies it a great deal.)

Comment: Hi Inafziger, for simplicity I would say yes on always having the wildcard in the same spot, so for example: `char bytes[] = {0x66, 0x(wildcard), 0x63};` — no hurry, so just let me know, thanks again.

Comment: @Mr.President I added the code to check with a wildcard.  Note that I used a character array created from the data since we will be parsing every character.

Comment: Thank you so very much Inafziger, I seriously appreciate it! ;-)

Comment: @Inafziger, quick question (hopefully) — If I wanted to not replace the wildcard with something different, but rather leave what was there, what would I need to add? thanks very much.